# Changing MD5 to sha256 or AES-256 SHA

Tags: php, hash, aes, md5, sha

Can someone teach me on how to changing MD5 to sha256 or AES 256 SHA, right now iam using md5 encryption in register handler and login handler so how can I change the code? Is it any disadvantage when I change it?

register_handler.php

```
$password = ""; //password

//Password
$password = strip_tags($_POST['reg_password']); //Remove html tags
$password2 = strip_tags($_POST['reg_password2']); //Remove html tags

if(empty($error_array)) {
    $password = md5($password); //Encrypt password before sending to database
```

this is my login_handler.php

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['login_button'])){
 $email = filter_var($_POST['log_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

 $_SESSION['log_email'] = $email; //Store email into session variable 
$password = md5($_POST['log_password']); //Get password
```

Comment: Use `password_hash`. And don't `strip_tags` on passwords. Don't change them!

Comment: @tkausl what do you mean by "don't change them"?

Comment: "Is it any disadvantage when I change it?" No, it's the other way around. The MD5 (128 bit) hashing is less secure than SHA (256 bit (or more using sha-512)).

Comment: `md5` is a hash rather than a form of encryption and is generally considered to be broken so its use is highly discouraged

Comment: @zhafranmazzuan I mean do not touch passwords, do not preprocess them. Neither `strip_tags` nor any other stripping or escaping function. Stripping tags on a password is a huge security-risk.

Comment: @tkausl after I change the strip_tags to password_hash, so how can change the md5 to sha256?

Comment: You misunderstood me. `password_hash` was the replacement for `md5` and the `strip_tags` just gets removed completely, there is no replacement for that, you don't need to strip anything.

Comment: @tkausl isn't it safer to filter `$password` in case it contains js or php tags? I realize that there is not much risk for code injection with passwords, but isn't allways better to sanitize user input?

Comment: @t.m.adam Since you hash the password, all tags - if it contained any - are gone anyway. And given OPs code as example, it makes your login less secure, as it considers the passwords `<>`, `<hello>` and `<k6G(%b978&>` to be equal

Comment: @tkausl i understand that the risk is very small but it's better to be safe than sorry. You never know how some developer might process passwords. And if it contains tags you could just prompt the user to enter a new password.